# The servlet doesn't come back to the previous page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

This is my web servlet. its first job is to retrieve from the db a list of countries and print out in a select form element. for this point everything works. When I click the submit button in the form, I call the servlet through the `action="/submit"`. Let suppose that I don't insert any username then when I submit the form. the validateSignUpForm return `true. Instead to return to signup page, I am in submit page. I don't understand. When the validationErrorFlag is true I should come back to signup page instead to be in submit page again. Where is the error?

```
    @WebServlet(name = "SignUpServlet", urlPatterns =
    {
        "/signup"
})
public class SignUpServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @EJB
    private UtilBeanInterface utilBean;

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.setAttribute("CountriesList", utilBean.getContriesList());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/signup.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String confirm_password = request.getParameter("confirm_password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String zipcode = request.getParameter("zip_code");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String homenumber_code = request.getParameter("homenumber_code");
        String homenumber = request.getParameter("homenumber");
        String mobilenumber_code = request.getParameter("mobilenumber_code");
        String mobilenumber = request.getParameter("mobilenumber");

        boolean validationErrorFlag = false;

        validationErrorFlag = utilBean.validateSignUpForm(username, 
                                                          password, 
                                                          confirm_password, 
                                                          email, 
                                                          name, 
                                                          surname, 
                                                          address, 
                                                          city, 
                                                          zipcode, 
                                                          country, 
                                                          homenumber_code, 
                                                          homenumber, 
                                                          mobilenumber_code, 
                                                          mobilenumber, 
                                                          request);

        if(validationErrorFlag == true)
        {
            doGet(request, response);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

JSP PAGE

```
<article class="container_12">
    <section id="signupform" class="grid_5">
        <h4>Registrazione membri</h4>
        <p>(*) Campi richiesti</p>
        <h6>I tuoi dati d'accesso su VolaConNoi.it</h6>
        <form action="submit" method="POST">
            <div>
                <label>Username* <span class="advice">(max 16 caratteri)</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="username" autofocus>
                <c:if test="${!empty usernameInvalid}">
                    <p class="errorSignUp">Errore: inserisci un username valido</p>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${!empty usernameAlreadyExist}">
                    <p class="errorSignUp">Errore: l'username è già in uso</p>
                </c:if>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password*</label>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Conferma Password*</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>E-mail*</label>
                <input type="email" name="email">
            </div>

            <br/>

            <h6>Dati Personali</h6>
                <div>
                    <label>Nome*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Cognome/i*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Indirizzo*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Città*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>CAP*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zip_code">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Paese*</label>
                    <select name="country">
                        <c:forEach items="${CountriesList}" var="country">
                            <option value="${country.iso}">${country.nicename}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Fisso</label>
                    <select name="homenumber_code">
                        <c:forEach items="${CountriesList}" var="country">
                            <option value="${country.phonecode}">${country.nicename} (+${country.phonecode})</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <input type="text" name="homenumber">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Mobile*</label>
                    <select name="mobilenumber_code">
                        <c:forEach items="${CountriesList}" var="country">
                            <option value="${country.phonecode}">${country.nicename} (+${country.phonecode})</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" name="mobilenumber">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrati"/>
                </div>
        </form>
        <div id="signupfooter"></div>
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MainControllerServlet",
        loadOnStartup = 1,
        urlPatterns = {"/signup",
                       "/submit"})
```

with:

```
String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";
```

Even if `userPath = "/signup";` you'll never get to the signup servlet, because you appeneded that ".jsp" in there.

Also, if you ever did get to `/signup` it looks like it would be an infinite loop forwarding to itself over and over.

BTW, it would probably be a lot simpler to actually make separate servlets for each different operation than to double up on them and do this kind of string manipulation.

Comment: DO you think it could be a better idea to separate this operation in different servlet?

Comment: What I'd say is: is it really convenient to create a servlet to ONLY get country list? I mean it is convenient create a servlet to to this only operation:             request.setAttribute("CountriesList", utilBean.getContriesList());
?

Comment: Convenience vs unintended side-effects, convenience loses.

Comment: I was thinking to use init() servlet method to get country list when the servlet is loaded and doPost() method when the form is submitted. Do you think it could work?

Comment: Country list comes from database. it is retrieved through JPA inserted into an EJB

Comment: I don't really see why you want to use the init method. You could, I suppose, use doGet for one getting the country list, and doPost for the submission of the form. Either that, or use two servlets. In some frameworks you can annotate methods such that they become seperate servlets. If making two java files is too inconvenient, you could look into one of those.

Comment: You could use init for filling the bean with data, but you'd still need to use doGet to pass the contents of the bean to your JSP.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any framework. I'm using JavaEE along with GlassFish 4.1. The idea to separate the requests in doGet() and doPost(), it sounds good.

Comment: following your suggestion, I modified the servlet. I posted the solution